# Stop currently scheduled/running TimerTask

Tags: java, timertask

I have a GUI button with an ActionListener which calls the this TimerTask each second via the Timer.

import java.util.*;

```
public class TimerSchedule {

public static Timer RunTimer() {

final Timer run = new Timer();
TimerTask runTask = new TimerTask(){
public void run(){
System.out.println("Running");}};
run.schedule(runTask, 1000, 1000);
return run;
}

public static void EndTimer() {
Timer run = TimerSchedule.RunTimer();
run.cancel();
System.out.println ("cancel");  
}
}
```

How can I call EndTimer to cancel RunTimer? Clicking the button prints "cancel" fine.

Comment: Just call the `run.cancel()` method on the `Timer`.

Comment: Loop might be a misleading term here, perhaps that's a specific Java term that I've not yet come across. This code prints "Running" every second, ad infinitum, in a 'loop'

Comment: Incidentally, if you plan to do any GUI related things in your `Timer` then due to the Swing threading model you **must** use `javax.swing.Timer` and **not** `java.util.Timer` as you currently are doing.

Comment: You can call `cancel()` on the Timer instance as Boris says, if you declare the instance on class level.

Comment: It's not a loop. It's a TimerTask that is run again and again each second by the Timer. If you want it to stop do so, call cancel as proposed before.

Comment: Yep, trying to create a class with the cancel() method, but not having a lot of luck. `code`public static void EndTimer() {
 TimerTask run = TimerSchedule.runTask;
 run.cancel();

Comment: @BoristheSpider- `code` public static void StopTimer() {runTask.cancel();}     This code isn't working, could you tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Comment: I said `run.cancel()`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - Where do I place `run.cancel`? I see how it works, I don't understand how I keep `run.cancel` dormant, waiting to be invoked by the ActionListener, whilst still being able to _see_ the timer. Could you embellish? I clearly have a large gap in my understanding here...

Comment: There is hardly enough information here to answer that question. You need to keep a reference to your `Timer` and then call `cancel()` on it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider - I updated my question with some further information. Hopefully it shows enough detail to reveal what I'm doing wrong. Any help appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to read about the difference between instance and static class members. The [Oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) is a good place to start. You are starting one `Timer` and calling `cancel()` on an entirely different `Timer`.